# tf.string_split for a tensor of strings

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have a tensor which looks like

```
x = [b'1 2 3 4 5'
     b'3 2 1'
     b'1 2']
```

How can I split single strings of this tensor to numbers? When I apply `tf.string_split(x)` I get the following error:

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("StringSplit_1:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("StringSplit_1:1", shape=(?,), dtype=string), dense_shape=Tensor("StringSplit_1:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

When i try it with `tf.string_split(x).values`, i get the following tensor:

`x = [b'1' b'2' b'3' b'4' b'5' b'3 b'2 b'1' b'1 b'2']`

This is not what i want because the information which numbers belong together is gone. What i want is something like this

```
x = [[b'1' b'2' b'3' b'4' b'5']
     [b'3' b'2' b'1']
     [b'1' b'2']]
```

to cast these with `tf.string_to_number` to int32 in the next step.

Can anybody help me?